# iOS Timelime View

Tags: ios, view, timeline

I want to implement a timeline view. In which I need to have months (with dates) on top and many rows below that with a bar of time period. (very similar to [this image](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/24920149/Timeline-Calendar-Sample---DOC---DOC))

Please tell me, where should I start, like subclassing `UIScrollView` or using `drawRect`. And whether is it possible to use `UITableViewCell` for each row? Please show me the right direction.
thank you!

Comment: Please comment if question is unclear. I'll try to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this one, it will help you :-

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/multicolumntableviewforios

Comment: Thanks Arpit! It'll help me definitely.